# How do you use css transform with jquery and address window maximise inconsistency?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

**Documentation of attempts and pictures of the described problem:**

I am trying to resize a table responsively within [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is working just fine and even my table is working mostly fine. The problem I am having is that when the view port is resized (whether it be a desktop window, or the rendering of the page via a cell phone screen) the table will not resize in any kind of sensible manner. It does resize but not relative to its original position. It shrinks in place and loses its margin placement with the other elements on the page.

As you cans see I have tried a number of different methods represented by the commented sections. I have poured over at least 40 browser tabs searching for a viable solution to this. There is some little something I am missing and a good push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**What do I need to do to alleviate that margin so the table will remain top and left against the content above it and the view port left wall?**

> See my answer below for the solution for both transformation and maximise issue.

The incomplete jquery code I am using:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var hh = $(window).height();
    var tt = $(".gametable").width();

    var scle = 0.0;//parseFloat(tt) / parseFloat(ww);

    if (ww <= 688);
    {
        scle = parseFloat(ww) / parseFloat(tt);
        //$(".gametable").css("transform", "scale(" + scle.toString().substr(0, 4) + ")");
        $('.gametable').css({
          '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + scle.toString().substr(0, 4) + ')',
          '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + scle.toString().substr(0, 4) + ')',
          '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + scle.toString().substr(0, 4) + ')',
          '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + scle.toString().substr(0, 4) + ')',
          'transform'         : 'scale(' + scle.toString().substr(0, 4) + ')'
        });
    }

    $(".log").html($(".log").html() + scle.toString().substr(0, 4) + "<BR>");

//    $(".gametable").width($(".gamerow").css("width"));
//    $(".gametable").height($(".gamerow").css("width"));

//    $(".gametable").css("transform", "scale(0.75)");

    $(".gametable").css("position", "relative");
    $(".gametable").css("top", "0");
    $(".gametable").css("left", "0");
    $(".gametable").css("padding", "0");
//
//    $(".gamediv").css("position", "relative");
//    $(".gamediv").css("top", "0px");
//    $(".gamediv").css("left", "0px");
//    $(".gamediv").css("padding", "0px");

});
```

**A precise depiction of the stated behavior can be found in the pictures below:**

[image]
The table is on the left of the screen when both the window and the board are the same width: 688px.

[image]
But when using the code above, the table shrinks but it does not maintain position. This is my question. How to I make it not make that margin?

Lets reiterate. When I shrink the table using the transform method above, It creates an undesirable margin top and left of the table. What do I need to do to alleviate that margin so the table will remain top and left against the content above it and the view port left wall?

Comment: transform-origin: top left

Comment: Will you please post that as an answer so I can accept it. That did the trick. Thank you so very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With vals' help, I came up with a solution that resizes my table fully dynamically. Someone else can adapt my code how they need to to apply to their particular problem. My code also handles the issue of the operating system's "maximize" button at the corner of the view port in the desktop environment. This bit of code solves all issues with resizing my table in all the big 5 browsers and the mobile browsers I have access to. I hope this helps a million people. :)

As you can see below, the `$(window).resize(function()` event is wrapped inside the `$(document).ready(function()` event. This does two seperate but equal things:

- It prevents the `$(window).resize(function()` from being called an excessive number of times.
- It prevents the `$(window).resize(function()` from being called too early causing the values in the various width and height calls to be potentially skewed and incorrect.

This should work for all typical dynamic content resizing procedures.

Please take note vals' specific contribution of `transform-origin`. This keeps the content packed together the way it originally was before the `trasformation`.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        if ($(window).width() <= 700 || $(window).height() <= 800)
        {
            var sclw = ((parseFloat($(window).width()) - 30) / parseFloat($(".gametable").width())).toString().substr(0, 4);
            var sclh = ((parseFloat($(window).height()) - 120) / parseFloat($(".gametable").width())).toString().substr(0, 4);
            var sc = parseFloat(sclw) < parseFloat(sclh) ? sclw : sclh;

            $('.gametable').css({
              '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + sc + ')',
              '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + sc + ')',
              '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + sc + ')',
              '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + sc + ')',
              'transform'         : 'scale(' + sc + ')',
              'transform-origin'  : 'top left'
            });
            $('.mininfo').width(parseFloat($(window).width()) - 30);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.gametable').css({
              '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(1)',
              '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(1)',
              '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(1)',
              '-o-transform'      : 'scale(1)',
              'transform'         : 'scale(1)',
              'transform-origin'  : 'top left'
            });
            $('.mininfo').width($(".gametable").width());
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a media query in css instead of JavaScript for this? I prefer that normally because there's less of my own code that can go wrong...only style and the viewport specification.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries